# How to write to iCloud in Terminal? (Currently seems read-only)

Tags: terminal, icloud, bash

I have a bash function that writes to a markdown file. Here it is in its simplest form:

```
function n() {
   echo $@ >> path/file.md;
}
```

This works fine. However, when I change the path to an iCloud destination, nothing happens. No error is returned, but the markdown file is unchanged.

Terminal, though, has access to *read* the iCloud-based file. `tail path/file.md` indeed returns the last lines of the file.

Also, for clarification, the problem is not that iCloud isn't syncing cross devices. Even the local version of the file is unchanged.

Comment: What paths are you using *specifically*?  I can write to all folders (in Terminal) that sync with iCloud and OneDrive.

Comment: @Allan the file is `/Users/username/Library/Mobile Documents/com~apple~CloudDocs/Obsidian/record.md`

Comment: I've no quotes around it because those have returned errors for me

Comment: Please run the echo to the target file directly on the command line and then copy/paste both the command and any Output you get into the question. Also run `ls -l` on the file and add the result

Comment: Yes.  Please follow @nohillside 's instructions. Also, you want to [edit] the original question with the new information, please don't post it as a comment.